# My palm is dying. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: palm

I recently moved my palm (Dracaena?) from a corner inside house, to a corner on my balcony.  I live in a tropical country, where it is warm and humid all year.
The plant did not look too happy so I moved it back inside the house. The plant looks limp, top is falling, brown leaves 
What happened? And can it be saved?
Thanks for your advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a palm. Some kind of dracaena is a good guess.

Moving a plant to a new location can stress the plant and cause symptoms like you're seeing. More sun, more breeze, higher temps -- almost any change can cause some plants to drop their leaves. Moving it in stages might keep it from reacting so badly. A week or two in each spot should do.

If a stem is dying or just gets too tall and spindly, you can cut the top off (as much as youwant actually) and the remaining portion should make a new sprout or two and keep growing. Stick the part you cut off in some dirt and it will likely grow too.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar experience with two Dracaena-sprouts I rooted over months in water and planted them then outside into new soil. The leaves wilted and got soft and decolorized. Guess the change with too much suddenly caused this, because only the "sun-side" was affected.
But it recovered after I moved it to a more shadowy spot on the balcony. Guess the sudden change from "indoor room" to "sunny balcony" in June caused this.

I have very good results with rooting the cut stems in pure water.